# Is it possible to 'select' only certain fields of a navigation property when expanding a query

Tags: breeze

When gathering a large number of entities from the server we can use the `select` method to transfer only the data we need. I have a situation where much of the unwanted data is on navigation properties that must be included for one of their fields. How can I exclude the unwanted data from my query results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify the data that you want with the "select" operation.

Here is an example:

```
breeze.EntityQuery("Customers")
 .where(//Something)
 .select("Name, LastName, Address.ZipCode, Details.HasChildren");
```